# How can I used an entry from a Recordset as criteria in a MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver, recordset

I've been experimenting with PHP for the first time so I hope this isn't an obvious question. I have two tables in a database, one is called users the other is called articles. In the users table there is a field which contains the categories that the user wants to follow.  Using a recordset in Dreamweaver I can get the information for the current user through a recordset. This done in the code below.

```
'$row_UserDets['CatFollow']'
```

At the moment there are comma separated values in the field however I can change this. I now want to search the Article Table's Category Field and return all results with the those categories. So far I've tried this.

```
$query_usernews = "SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE CategoryOne IN ($row_UserDets['CatFollow']); $usernews = mysql_query($query_usernews, $database name) or die(mysql_error());
```

I hope that makes sense. I've tried it a few times in a number of different formats. As I've said I'm new to this and I might have been going about it completely the wrong way. man Thanks for your time.

Comment: Beware SQL injection! You'll have to use `mysql_real_escape`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$query_usernews = "SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE CategoryOne IN ({$row_UserDets['CatFollow']})";
```

Or simply:

```
$query_usernews = "SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE CategoryOne IN (" . $row_UserDets['CatFollow'] . ")";
```

As Romain stated in the comment, you need to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) proof your code (mysql_real_escape, or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) + [Prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)).

Comment: Thanks. That answered my question really well.